# Reference to not yet written object (supress warnings)

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings

Is there a way to make references to not yet written code?

Basically I just want to supress warnings that appear, when I write `\ref{}`, cause I happen to have references to things, that will come only later. However, I don't want the  missing reference warnings to clutter the log (which in any case is already big and confusing).

Comment: Well you must compile at least twice for avoid warnings and get the references right instead the **??** symbols when LaTeX can't find the label or the object to reference. You can put comments on your code to know where you must, in a future stage, add a label or an object. And you can also use the `todonotes` package that can help you to add colourful notes for remind you to add those things. This package includes also placeholder pictures also.

Comment: @Aradnix `todonotes` seems to be a good solution.

Comment: If your log is "large and confusing", first clean up current warnings. If (La)TeX issues a warning, more often than not something is wrong.  It might be mildly wrong (a line is too long to fit, in which case you should rewrite sometime, or something like it) or it could be more serious. Warnings about missing references *should not* be silenced, they are serious problems, that *must* be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress warnings using [`silence`](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence).

Below is a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{silence}% Filter out unwanted warnings and error messages
                                    % Remove all warnings issued by LaTeX that starts with
\WarningFilter[todo]{latex}
  {Reference }                      % 'Reference ' and
\WarningFilter[todo]{latex}
  {There were undefined references} % 'There were undefined references'

\ActivateWarningFilters[todo]% Activate the 'todo' warnings filter
\begin{document}

\section{A section}
See Section~\ref{sec:two} and~\ref{sec:three}.

\iffalse% Comment to insert this section
\section{Another section}\label{sec:two}
This is another section.
\fi% Comment to insert this section

\section{Yet another section}\label{sec:three}
This is yet another section.

\end{document}
```

The `.log` for the above example produces 0 warnings.

All warning filters are stored in a "family" called `todo`, which can be activated as needed.